# Python: Sort datetime in str format with lambda

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, lambda

I am using `sorted(response, key=lambda k: k['createDate'], reverse=False)` to get the most recent list members sorted to the front of the list. The problem is that my datetime is in string format `%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p`. If I do this sort, it will sort via string comparison and not datetime comparison. How do I work around this issue?

EDIT: Forgot to mention I am usin Python 3.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to parse your values to datetime objects in your key function:

```
from datetime import datetime

sorted(
    response,
    key=lambda k: datetime.strptime(k['createDate'], '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'),
    reverse=True,
)
```

Had your date format been *slightly* different, you could have used straight string sorting; ISO8601 dates (formatted to `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`) are lexicographically sortable.

I also changed the sort order; you want the order reversed, the most recent `datetime` value will be *higher* than those that precede it:

```py
>>> datetime(2014, 6, 11, 17, 16, 10) > datetime(2008, 9, 15, 12, 00, 00)
True
```

so the most recent values would be sorted to be the last elements if you don't reverse the sort.

Comment: Just to mention, `reverse=False` will give you the most recent list members at the _back_ (or end) of the list -- to sort in descending order (so most recent `createDate` is the first element), you need `reverse=True`.

Comment: @Eugene: true, updated.

Answer (score 2):

Just parse the results in your key function, something like this should do:

```
import datetime
def parse_timestamp_from_response(response):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(response['createDate'], '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')

sorted(response, key=parse_timestamp_from_response, reverse=False)
```